# How to build a function that return TextFragmentCollection based on PDF file url?

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose

I already have a searchable pdf, but I want to convert it into pdf with digital text...I already got the code, but, unfortunately there is no method GetTextFragment.. I have been looking for it in itext7, Aspose and iTextSharp, None of them have this..Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to get TextFragmentCollection where source file as parameter

This is one of the code I have tested, I need GetTextFragment()..

```
using System;
using Aspose.Pdf;
using Aspose.Pdf.Text;

public static void PDFSearchableToPDFNormal(String filename, String des_filename){
            Document pdfDocument = new Document(filename);

            Document newDocument = new Document();

            foreach (Page pdfPage in pdfDocument.Pages)
            {
                Page newPage = newDocument.Pages.Add();
                //There is no GetTextFragment() in Page definition, Is there any alternative ways?
                TextFragmentCollection textFragments = pdfPage.GetTextFragments();

                foreach (TextFragment textFragment in textFragments)
                {
                    TextFragment newTextFragment = new TextFragment(textFragment.Text);
                    newTextFragment.Position = textFragment.Position;
                    newPage.Paragraphs.Add(newTextFragment);
                }
            }
            newDocument.Save(des_filename);
}
```

Any ideas to retrieve pdf's textfragmentcollection?

I need an alternative ways to get pdf's TextFragmentCollection since GetTextFragment doesnt exists.

Comment: If so, is there any other ideas for an algorithm to converting every words in Searchable PDF to PDF other than get TextFragmentCollection..By searchable PDF, I mean, the content was an image, but every text are selectable..Therefore, I want to build a program that will copy every selected text, and paste it into new pdf at the exact position where they copy..And finally, it will save..

Comment: Please check the first code example on this page i.e. https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/net/search-and-get-text-from-pdf/ in order to get TextFragmentCollection from a PDF using Aspose.PDF for .NET. In case you still notice any issues, please create a post on Aspose.PDF official support forum where you will be assisted accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.